# ReferenceError: socket is not defined

Tags: python, node.js, python-2.7, socket.io

I have one python script which emit data to my node.js server each time a new value is recovered.

Here's my code client side (python script) :

```
from socketIO_client import SocketIO

...

def update_db(dateUpdate, res, nameIndex):
    try:
        with SocketIO('192.168.100.103', 8080) as socketIO:
             socketIO.emit('newValues', res)

    except Exception as e:
        print "error socketIO - Impossible to emit data \n"

    #Update database

while True:
    #If new value
        dateUpdate = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        update_db(dateUpdate, res, nameIndex[i])
        break
```

Here's my node.js server :

```
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var mysql = require("mysql");
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

var server = app.listen(8080);
console.log('Server listening on port 8080');

var io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.sockets.on('connection', function () {
    console.log("client connected");

    socket.on('newValues', function (data) {
            console.log("new values : "+data);      
    });
});
```

**Problem :**

Eache time my python script recieved new data and have to emit a message. My node server stop and display this error :

```
node server.js

Server listening on port 8080
client connected
C:\project\src\server\server.js:26

socket.on('newValues', function (data) {
    ^

ReferenceError: socket is not defined
    at Namespace.<anonymous> (C:\project\src\server\server.js:26:5)
    at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
    at Namespace.emit (events.js:182:7)
    at Namespace.emit (C:project\node_modules\socket.io\lib\nam
espace.js:206:10)
    at C:\project\node_modules\socket.io\lib\namespace.js:174:14

    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:452:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:381:13)
```

Anyone Know the error ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

socket is not defined.  You need to pass the socket in to your io.sockets.on callback function.

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {    //Pass socket here
    console.log("client connected");

    socket.on('newValues', function (data) {
        console.log("new values : "+data);      
    });
}
```

Edit:  This is my first glance best guess solution.  I am not very experienced with sockets.io.  I am just looking at the docs (there is a similar example at this link) http://socket.io/docs/

Comment: The comment "Pass socket here" helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

When you write

```
socket.on( 'newValues' , ...)
```

It is assuming that "socket" is a variable. And if it is, it has not been defined before that call.

I don't know IO well, but try this instead:

```
io.sockets.on( 'newValues' , ...)
```